# swiftでAVAudioPCMBufferを使って書いたコードをobjective-Cに直したい。

Tags: swift, objective-c, avfoundation

swiftでAVAudioPCMBufferを使ってbufferに値を書き込んでサイン波を鳴らすことは、
http://www.tmroyal.com/playing-sounds-in-swift-audioengine.html
を参考にして出来ました。
これをobjective-Cで書きたいのですが、bufferに値を書き込むところでメッセージの送り方が分からなくて難儀しています。
先のサイトのswiftだと、ここです。

```
    for var i = 0; i < Int(buffer.frameLength); i+=Int(n_channels) {
        var val = sinf(441.0*Float(i)*2*Float(M_PI)/sr)

        buffer.floatChannelData.memory[i] = val * 0.5
    }
```

これをobjective-Cで書こうとしたときに、buffer.floatChannelDataまでは補完で出てくるのですが、それに続くmemory[i]は補完に出て来ません。
てっきり,

```
buffer.floatChannelData.memory[i] = val;
```

で書けるものと思っていたのですが、どうやって書けばよいのでしょうか？

どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

[AVAudioPCMBuffer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPCMBuffer_Class/index.html)のドキュメントより、`floatChannelData`は`UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>>`として宣言されていますが、`float`のポインタへのconstポインタを意味しています。

Swiftはポインタを直接扱えないため、`memory`を経由してアクセスしますが、間接演算子を用いて以下のように書き換えられます。

```
*buffer.floatChannelData[i] =  val;
```

Objective-Cというよりも、C言語のポインタの知識が必要になるかと思います。